# Ubuntu 15.04 LTS tablet cannot parse or open package lists

Tags: apt, updates, m10

I just got an Ubuntu Tablet M10 through BQ (see Ubuntu site for details). I am trying to get things set up so I can properly use the tablet.  I want to get wine installed so I can use Amazon Kindle Reader app.

I have found that it doesn't use `sudo`, so I am simply using `apt-get install`, but I get the error:

```
 The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have tried the command:  `apt-get clean`

I get the error:

```
Not using locking for read only lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

I am not sure what that means . . .

Next I do: `apt-get update`

I get about half of the files update, the rest failed to fetch, and I get the `Not using locking...` like above.

I then do: `apt-get upgrade`

This gives an error that it is unable to write to `/var/cache/apt/` followed by the same `Not using locking...`

The tablet was supposed to be 16.04 LTS, but I doubt it is since the downloads that were accomplished show they are from 'wiley' not 'xenial'.

So basically, I am stuck. Being somewhat new to ubuntu in general, I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the tablet shipped with ubuntu 15.04 (touch OTA-10). It is not possible to use apt-get out of the box. Either you need to remount root to be writable but this apparently prevents updates from working, or you can use apt-get in a chroot (container). This is needed because the dep packages are not compatible with ARM architecture.

I would also like to install some useful programs too. I'm hoping that the upcomning upgrade to 16.04 (OTA-11) will make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use terminal and enter this command :
android-gadget-service enable writable
This make the rootfs writable and apt-get will be ok after a reboot.